# Unsure as to how certain sections of this function work

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

While writing a login system for a web project Im working on I came across the problem of binding an unknown number of parameters and found this function on the php manual pages. I always like to fully understand an peice of code I put into anything Im working on and Im quite stumped as to how a few sections of this function work.

Ive commented everything I think i understand(if im wrong please let me know) and left my major questions in the comments:

```
<?php
    function getresult($stmt) {

        //Define var for holding the result
        $result = array();

        //asign metadata of the statments result
        $metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();

        //grab the feilds from the metadata and assign to var
        $fields = $metadata->fetch_fields();

        //for loop with internal break
        for (;;) {

            //pointers array (not sure why this is an array and not a stdClass)
            $pointers = array();

            //row empty class
            $row = new stdClass();


            //set pointers array to the value of the passed statement (casting $pointers to mysqli_stmt class I assume(?)   
            $pointers[] = $stmt;

            //iterate through all fields
            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                //each time set $fieldname to the name from the current element of $fields
                $fieldname = $field->name;

                //?? this is my big issue no idea whats going on here $row hasnt been set from what i can see, and no idea why its being refered to by reference and not value
                $pointers[] = &$row->$fieldname;
            }

            //call bind result for all values
            call_user_func_array(mysqli_stmt_bind_result, $pointers);

            //internal break if 
            if (!$stmt->fetch()) {

                //if there is nothing left to fetch break
                break;
            }

            //set the result
            $result[] = $row;
        }

        //free resources
        $metadata->free();

        //return result
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It creates a new `stdClass` (pretty much like an empty array) for each row.

With `$pointers[] = &$row->$fieldname;` a reference to the various fields of the object is stored.

After that, `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` is used to tell mysqli where to store the data of the next row. When calling `$stmt->fetch()`, mysqli assigns it to the references in `$pointers` and thus to the fields in the `$row` object.

`$pointers` is an array because `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` expects one. Objects do not have 0..n fields but rather named values - so to assign columns based on their position using a non-associative array makes much more sense.

---

It does pretty much the same what [`mysqli::fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) does.

Comment: So each time it loops through it sets a new element of $pointers[] to the memory location of $row with the field name, passes the $pointers array to mysqli_stmt_bind_result() with call_user_func_array() then returns the $row object as opposed to the $pointers array. And $pointers is only needed for call_user_func_array(). Is that it?

Comment: Yes, `$pointers` contains references to the fields in `$row`.